# Is it legitimate to have business logic inside a finally block?

Tags: java, dry, business-logic, finally

I have a method entangled with control structures. It has many ways to exit. Before leaving the method I need to do some final processing. Instead of repeating the same logic before each exit or refactoring that logic in a method and calling it several times it seem handy to leave that in a finally block. Is it really a legitimate use of finally or am I abusing it?

Comment: If your Program should e.g. exit (ThreadDeath), your Buisness Logic is executed. I recommend you to catch Exceptions and execute your Buisness logic after that.

Comment: I recommend refactoring the whole thing so that it's not as convoluted as you make it sound.

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. Make sure your code in finally doesn't throw any exception other wise you might need a try block in finally too

Comment: It depends. If you have that much entanglement in a single control structure then it's likely missing refactorings.

Comment: Also it tdepends on how mission-critical it is: remember that `finally` is not guaranteed to kick in simply because power outages, people tripping over cords, VM crashes, kill-9, etc. are all real things that can happen.

Comment: `try { generateEnergy(); } finally { shutdownNuclearReactor();  }`? Uhhhm - no. But it indeed sounds like it should first be tackled with a refactoring. If you provide some code (maybe even sketchy, showing the messed up control flow and how you want to (ab)use `finally`), one can give a more focused answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finally` is there for a reason, to add logic that must be execute before the exiting block

It's a valid choice for a method if you don't want/need to use [AOP/AspectJ](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html)

Notice you may **have to use** `finally` for release resources as `Connection`

For example you can use it when you must audit/log or do autonomous transaction at the end of the method

As @DaveNewton comment, in some cases there might be a better way of refactoring/separating logic, but you can't ignore that it's a valid usage